# Maven doesn't use local JRE/JDK

Tags: java, maven

When i try to compile(running maven install) in the eclipse,i am getting an error of not compatibility.It seems that,for some reason,maven uses old jre/jdk and doesn't use the one specified in the Path env. variable.Even though when i run mvn -v,it outputs that maven uses the correct version(on my local machine)

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/databasePackage/implementations/DBConnection.java:[132,21] try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/databasePackage/implementations/DBConnection.java:[223,50] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/adv/DBConnection.java:[64,38] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/adv/DBConnection.java:[80,21] try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/databasePackage/implementations/ObjectComparators.java:[21,48] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/adv/ObjectComparators.java:[21,48] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/adv/DatabaseTable.java:[420,51] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[INFO] 7 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.142 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-14T09:44:36+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project PetClinic: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/databasePackage/implementations/DBConnection.java:[132,21] try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/databasePackage/implementations/DBConnection.java:[223,50] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/adv/DBConnection.java:[64,38] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/adv/DBConnection.java:[80,21] try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/databasePackage/implementations/ObjectComparators.java:[21,48] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/adv/ObjectComparators.java:[21,48] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Barracuda/Desktop/Projects/Eclipse Projects/PetClinicWeb/src/main/java/com/model/adv/DatabaseTable.java:[420,51] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

How should i fix this?And can i do it without specifying each time in the POM.xml which version to use,but to tell maven to use the Path env. var. ?
Here is what is specified in the eclipse:

[image]

This is the JAVA_HOME env. var.

[image]

This is the MAVEN_HOMEenv. var.
[image]

Here — the outputs of mvn -v and java -version
[image]

[image]

Here is the PATH env. var:
.[image]

And here is my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.arslan</groupId>
    <artifactId>PetClinic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Pet Clinic Web Application</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Even running mvn install from command line doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the following in your POM:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

The reason is the following: Even with a correctly configured JDK 1.8, you can build with different compatibility levels (1.7, 1.6, ...). Without giving a version, Maven will build with a very old one.